# PHP function fails to return correct result after ~1000 ajax posts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm debugging some code and in order to do so I am repeatedly making ajax post to a PHP script on my localhost Apache24 server. In simple terms, the PHP script takes an integer value and returns a different data string depending on the input integer.

I'm stepping through numerous integer values with a for loop on the javascript side, starting at x=1. I've noticed, however, that after ~980 ajax posts, the PHP function stops returning the correct data; it seems to only return the data for x = 980, even as x continues to increment. Console.log confirms that the x value doesn't hang at 980.

I initially thought maybe the script was buggy but then I restarted the loop at x = 980 and, sure enough, the php script worked fine until x = ~1900, when it stopped working again.

Is there a reason the PHP script fails to work after ~980 requests? I have received no errors on either the web side or server side.

```
       function interpretDisplay(input_string) {
            var display = input_string.split("?");

            for (var x = 0; x < 16; x++) {                    
                document.getElementById("ids").innerHTML = display + " ";
            }
        }

        function runDisplay(x) {
            values[1]+= "&seed=" + x;
            $.post("test.php", values[1], function(data) {
                console.log(x);
                if (x % 1 == 0) {
                    interpretDisplay(data);                        
                }

                if (x < 1000) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        runDisplay(x+1);
                    }
                        , 10);
                }
            });
        }

        var url = window.location.href;
        var values = url.split('?');

        runDisplay(1);
```

Comment: Could it have something to do with the speed at witch that calls are being made.

Comment: I've used a timeout to test for this, and it appears to not make a difference unfortunately.

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: post updated with javascript code. The php code is too massive to realistically share

Comment: looks like a bad science experiment ... check server logs

Comment: I changed x < 1000 to x < 10000 . I up to 10k with no problem. Definitely slows down a bit after 3k. The page I call returns nothing. Server on a remote linux box. I put the x value in a text box on the page. Do you want to send all the previous seeds. The 10000 request has seed=1 through seed=10000 .

Comment: Server logs show nothing out of the ordinary. Looks like this is a mystery! Luckily it doesn't impact things too heavily